# Recommend me phone with multiple sim slots

Tags: smartphones

Number of slots must be many. Main purpose is to store whatsapp sms and that's it.

Cheap price.

Cheapest cost per sim.

Being able to run multiple whatsapp account is a plus. So something like secure folder feature in Samsung

Comment: If you want multiple whatsapp accounts, you need multiple phones AFAIK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Gigaset GS190 32GB Grey is €100 and has dual sim, about as cheap as you can go with dual sim. There are cheaper options, but I don't know if those can run whatsapp.

Comment: I got something cheaper but your answer suggests that dual sim is most cost effective